# MemSQL Partition has no master instance

Tags: singlestore

Running queries on a MemSQL tables returns the following error:

```
Error Code: 1777. Partition db_name:0 has no master instance.
```

I understand MemSQL Enterprise avoids this error appearing in the first place; however, I tried dropping the table, truncating data, and restarting the cluster several times, yet I still get the same error. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a 2 node cluster. First node has master and leaf and 2nd only leaf. For some queries I get `Partition db_name:1 has no master instance`. `SHOW LEAVES` show both leaves online.

Answer (score 1):

Does "SHOW LEAVES" show all leaf nodes as online?  In redundancy 1 you need all leaves online to run queries.  Run REMOVE LEAF if you want to permanently remove an offline leaf from the cluster.